# Angular, using template variable in another place in the same template does not work

Tags: angular, templates, variables

In my template I have:

```
<input *ngIf="!radio" #chk [disabled]="loadingInProggress || !currentDimensionExists || !checkCurrentMetaID()" tabindex="-1"
        type="checkbox" (change)="checkboxChanged(chk.checked);" [(ngModel)]="active" class="dataset-checkbox" />

<div *ngIf="loadingCompleted && chk.checked" 
        class="colorSelector" 
        [(colorPicker)]="hexColor" (colorPickerChange)="colorPickerChange()"
        [ngStyle]="{'background':hexColor}">
</div>
```

I cannot use the chk.checked in the ngIf to select on base on the value of chk.checked. I get this error in js console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined
```

Why is this?

Comment: yes, but isn't the value "checked"? chk.calue gives the same error. The "chk" seems to be undefined here, so I don't know how to get it properly.

Comment: You can get this error if `radio` is true. In this case, the `<input *ngIf="!radio" #chk>` is not included, hence `#chk` is `undefined`. Can you try to remove `*ngIf="!radio"` for the test?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle worked thanks. you can put up your comment as an aswer. So that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chk` is defined here :

```
<input *ngIf="!radio" #chk [...]>
```

If `radio` is true, this `<input>` is not included in the DOM resulting in `chk` being `undefined`.

As a result, `chk.checked` will produce the error in this extract :

```
<div *ngIf="loadingCompleted && chk.checked" [...]>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
*ngIf="loadingCompleted && chk?.checked"
```